# Client certificate authentication in WebView

Tags: android, ssl, webview, ssl-certificate, android-webview

I'm writing an Android App which view a `https` `url` in a `webview` . This `webpage` uses a self-signed Certificate for SSL and requires a Client Certificate for Authentication.
how i can pass certificate with `webview`

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a WebViewClient object to your WebView class. When a server requires Client authentication, the WebView is notified through the `onReceivedClientCertRequest` of the WebViewClient object.

Example:

MyWebClient class.

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, ClientCertRequest request) {
       //HERE YOU CAN DO SOME STUFF TO RETRIEVE KEY AND CERTIFICATES
        request.proceed(mPrivateKey, mCertificates);
    }
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError( view,  errorCode,
                description,  failingUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("my_url.com");
}
```

The method `proceed(PrivateKey k, X509Certificate[] chain)` take the client private key and a certificates chain in order to accomplish SSL 2-way handshake.